# How can I perform arithmetic on a list integers and some other exact numbers and get decimal numbers in the result?

Tags: numerics, core-language

I want to do a simple calculation with a list with Pi and 10^-6 and get a list of decimal numbers as the result.

```
List1={380, 421, 430, 515, 498}
Solve[Pi*(List1*10^-6)]
```

It gave me this:

> ```
> Solve[{(19 \[Pi])/50000, (421 \[Pi])/1000000, (43 \[Pi])/100000, (103 \[Pi])/200000, (249 \[Pi])/500000]
> ```

`Solve` did not output the answer in decimal. I want the answers in a list like the one shown below.

```
{0.001234646, 0.001372876, 0.00140115, 0.001674469, 0.001627345}
```

Please help.

Comment: Look up `N[]`.${}$

Comment: This is not a correct usage of `Solve` in the first place. Its not ever clear what you are intending.

Comment: What is a "formulation"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the values

```
vals = {380, 421, 430, 515, 498};
```

here are two ways to force *Mathematica* to do arithmetic on these values that produces results expressed in your computer's native floating point numbers.

```
Pi vals 1.*^-6
```

and

```
Pi vals 10^-6 // N
```

The first one works because *Mathematica* has an evaluation rule that in effect says: if any number in a computation is a machine floating point number, coerce the results into machine floats.

The second one does the whole computation with exact numbers (those that you show in the `Solve` output you posted) and then passes the list of exact results to the numerical evaluation function [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html), which coerces the exact numbers in the list into machine floats. `N` can do some other things, but this is the most common way it is used. You can also write this in two other ways

```
N[Pi vals 10^-6]
```

and

```
N @ Pi vals 10^-6
```

That is, `N` can be written as a standard function, a pre-fixe operator, or a post-fix operator.

Note that there is no need to use `Solve` or `Map` to make this simple numeric computation across a list of values. Almost all the numeric functions in *Mathematica* have a attribute called [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) that makes them automatically map across the elements of a list.